# Access to root application support macos java

Tags: java, objective-c, macos

I need to save data inside the `/Library/Application Support/` of macOS within a java application. To access the user application data, I know I can use `System.getProperty("user.home")` but I want the one from the root, not the user. I see some applications storing data inside this, is there a way to do it within java?

If not in java, i am loading a obj-c library, is it possible in obj-c to elevate privileges so my java application have access to that folder?

Comment: Did you try to launch application with root privileged user.

Comment: This is what i am asking, i have no idea how to do this inside a java mac application. No answer online.

Comment: [Elevating privileges safely](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html) & [Authorization Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/authorization_services?language=objc). Don't elevate privileges of your Java application, write a helper and use it from your Java application.

Comment: Yes, i was looking at our installer (install4j) in order to give permissions to this new folder inside /Library/Application support/(company_name) so i can download my data inside. I don't know if this or using a helper inside my java application is better. My java application will not elevate privileges, only the installer. @zrzka

Comment: I have posted an answer using authopen but a moderator deleted it; I was short of time and did not post a coding example. I have edited with a coding example and I flagged it so that hopefully he will undelete it. You do not have to elevate privileges of your Java application; whenever you want to write to /Library/Application Support/ the mac authentication window pops up for credentials which apply exclusively to writing to the file. It works perfectly. If the moderator does not undelete my answer I will post it again.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an interactive program then using [authopen](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002589-SW5) would be perfect, otherwise I would use [launchd](https://www.launchd.info/).

I just noticed that this answer had been deleted. Why would someone delete the right answer?

Here is a simplified example to illustrate the use of authopen to answer the question:

```
package macos4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MacOS4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String destinationFileName = "/Library/Application Support/tempFile/";
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/libexec/authopen", "-c", "-w", "-a", destinationFileName);
        builder.redirectInput(new File("src/resources", "input.txt"));
        builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        process.destroy();
    }
}
```

This will create **tempFile** if it does not exist and write to it the contents of **input.txt** from the resources package. It will pop up for authentication:
[image: authopen authentication request]
which means there is no need to pipe the password to the subprocess.

For very important considerations regarding the need to prevent external processes to block on IO buffers see [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/FIO07-J.+Do+not+let+external+processes+block+on+IO+buffers).

What if you want your job to run unattended? Time for launchd, but keep in mind that the entire program will run as root, unlike the interactive option, which I posted above, where only the file operations run  as root. I wrote this simple program that I want to run every 5 minutes. Every time it runs it will add a line to "/Library/Application Support/tempFile" with the current date and time; every 30 minutes it will overwrite the file and start over, but keeping just the last timestamp. Here is the program:

```
package maclaunchd;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MacLaunchd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            File tempFile = new File("/Library/Application Support/tempFile");
            if (!tempFile.exists()) {
                tempFile.createNewFile();
            }
            FileTime creationTime = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(tempFile.toPath(), "creationTime");
            boolean append = (System.currentTimeMillis() - creationTime.toMillis() <= 1800000);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, append);
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
                bw.write(sdf.format(date) + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MacLaunchd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a launchd job definition which I called “maclaunchd.MacLaunchd.daemon.plist”. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>wheel</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>maclaunchd.MacLaunchd.daemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
        <string>-jar</string>
        <string>/Users/enta/NetBeansProjects/MacLaunchd/dist/MacLaunchd.jar</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/enta/NetBeansProjects/MacLaunchd/dist/err.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/enta/NetBeansProjects/MacLaunchd/dist/out.log</string>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>300</integer>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/enta/NetBeansProjects/MacLaunchd/dist/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Next I copied the file to the right place, loaded it and started it:

```
sudo cp maclaunchd.MacLaunchd.daemon.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/maclaunchd.MacLaunchd.daemon.plist
sudo launchctl start maclaunchd.MacLaunchd.daemon
```

If you cat "/Library/Application Support/tempFile" you will see the date being written to it every 5 minutes. To stop, unload and remove the job run:

```
sudo launchctl stop maclaunchd.MacLaunchd.daemon
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/maclaunchd.MacLaunchd.daemon.plist
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/maclaunchd.MacLaunchd.daemon.plist
```

Now you have two options to write to "/Library/Application Support/”.